# Play framework 1.2.5 template error

Tags: templates, playframework, internationalization, playframework-1.x

Please help. I get the following error when I try to load main page:

```
Error during the 500 response generation

Template execution error (In /app/views/main.html around line 12)
Execution error occured in template /app/views/main.html. Exception raised was NullPointerException : null.

play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:86)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:272)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:282)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:202)
    at play.server.PlayHandler.serve500(PlayHandler.java:774)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.i18n.Messages.getMessage(Messages.java:97)
    at play.i18n.Messages.get(Messages.java:46)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.__getMessage(GroovyTemplate.java:441)
    at /app/views/main.html.(line:12)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:247)
    ... 5 more
```

Here is my line 12 in main.html:
`<span>&nbsp;&{"navTab.appName"}</span>`
I have conf/messages file and appropriate key, but app still not sees it

Answer (score 0):

I think your code have some problems.

Please post your main.html code here, and maybe I can help.

In other way, please open Messages in Eclipse (Ctrl+T and type Messages, find package play.i18n), and check line 97. Confirm your code is using defaults var or not?

I use play framework 1.2.5 long time, and very big project. It's no problem like this.

Comment: If you want more information or clarification then you should leave a comment over the particular thread.